# options for exceptions on trigger before update

Tags: sqlite

I wanna create two trigger in sqlite. One trigger to stop updates and one trigger to change the inserted date. My Problem is that I find no solution to update an inserted value without activate the first trigger. Is there an option in sqlite to disable the trigger or to say dont allow updates, without updates on one column?

```
create trigger if not exists update_buchung before update on Buchung <br>
 begin <br>
  select RAISE(FAIL, "UPDATE NOT ALLOWED"); <br>
 end;<br>

 CREATE TRIGGER if not exists insert_buchung AFTER INSERT  ON Buchung <br>
 BEGIN <br>
  update Buchung SET Datum = datetime('now') WHERE ID = NEW.ID; <br>
 END;<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do away with the **insert_buchung** TRIGGER, but instead define the column using either :-

```
......., Datum TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

or

```
......., Datime TEXT DEFAULT (datetime('now'))
```

Consider :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS buchung;
CREATE TABLE buchung (othercolumn TEXT, Datum TEXT DEFAULT (datetime('now')), otherDtaum TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO buchung (othercolumn) VALUES('x'),('y'),('z');
SELECT * FROM buchung;
```

This demonstrates both and results in :-

[image]

i.e. The current date time is set when the row(s) is(are) inserted.

**However**, the **insert_buchung** TRIGGER could be (*the WHEN clause assumes just the one condition*) :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS update_buchung BEFORE UPDATE ON Buchung
WHEN old.Datum IS NOT NULL -- <<<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, "UPDATE NOT ALLOWED");
END;
```

As an example :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS buchung;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_buchung;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insert_buchung;
-- CREATE TABLE buchung (othercolumn TEXT, Datum TEXT DEFAULT (datetime('now')), otherDtaum TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS buchung (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,othercolumn TEXT, Datum TEXT);
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS update_buchung BEFORE UPDATE ON Buchung
    WHEN old.Datum IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT RAISE(FAIL, "UPDATE NOT ALLOWED");
    END;
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS insert_buchung AFTER INSERT ON Buchung 
    BEGIN 
        update Buchung SET Datum = datetime('now') WHERE ID = NEW.ID; 
    END;

INSERT INTO buchung (othercolumn) VALUES('x'),('y'),('z');
SELECT * FROM buchung;
```

Results in :-

[image]